# Mariadb Docker-compose named volumes work but not the Disk path

Tags: docker, docker-compose, mariadb, keycloak

There is a problem with using the disk volumes in the MySQL/MariaDB databases in Docker-compose mode. Here're the not-working (disk mount) and the one that is working (named volume). I am asking help to get the disk-mount fixed so that i can establish a way to backup my data.

This does not work properly (I have 777 permission set on the folder)

```
version: '3'

services:
  mysql:
    # image: docker.io/mariadb:11.0.2
    image: mariadb:latest
    environment:
      MARIADB_DATABASE: dbkc
      MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MARIADB_PASSWORD: admin
      MARIADB_USER: admin
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    volumes:
      - ~/Downloads/mysqldata:/var/lib/mysql
```

Here's a screenshot from Workbench (Note that the tables fetching isn't fully working - note "Tables could not be fetched"):

[image]

This one works (Named volume) fine:

```
version: '3'

services:
  mysql:
    # image: docker.io/mariadb:11.0.2
    image: mariadb:latest
    environment:
      MARIADB_DATABASE: dbkc
      MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MARIADB_PASSWORD: admin
      MARIADB_USER: admin
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    volumes:
      - my-datavolume:/var/lib/mysql
    
volumes:
  my-datavolume:
```

[image]

Anyone has experienced this same issue? Do you know what the disk-mount didn't work but the named volume did. Because of this issue Keycloak instance isn't starting. I am trying to get my compose file to use the disk persistence now, so I can back them up. This issue keeps me from moving forward. Any help much appreciated!

I tried changing the disk directory volume to a named volume. Both need to work the same way, but only the named volume really work. (I'm using a Mac M1 btw).

Log files from MariaDB:

- MariaDB Named Volume Docker Logs
  -- https://pastebin.com/XsjuhXHz
- MariaDB Disk Folder Volume Docker Logs
  -- https://pastebin.com/vFecK7Qh
  Notice the entry `Warning] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /var/lib/mysql/ is case insensitive`.

Comment: If that helps, this works fine:
``docker run --name mariadb -v ~/Downloads/mysqldata:/var/lib/mysql -e MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD=pass -p:3306:3306 -d mariadb:latest``

Answer (score 0):

Oh my goodness.. this was solved in the most strangest way!! Just adding a network to the compose file worked.

```yaml
version: '3'

services:
  mysql:
    image: docker.io/mariadb:11.0.2
    environment:
      MARIADB_DATABASE: dbkc
      MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MARIADB_PASSWORD: admin
      MARIADB_USER: admin
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    volumes:
      - /var/data/mariadb1:/var/lib/mysql
    networks:
      demo_mesh:
        aliases:
          - mysql

networks:
  demo_mesh: {}
```

Does anyone know why this worked? This to me seem like a but getting covered by adding a network! Either-way I am going ahead with having a network there.

Just for comparison, new logs: https://pastebin.com/hP1suYac

The MySQL Workbench has no trouble connecting and refreshing tables now.